# Replace array call with function call

Tags: regex

Is it possible to do such kind of replacement with regular expression (doesn't matter what kind of regex language reference tho)?

#### Original:

*Blabla* caseInsensitiveKnownFixedWord[**thisRandomWordMustRemainUntouched**] *more blabla*

#### Replaced:

*Blabla* myNewWord(**thisRandomWordMustRemainUntouched**) *more blabla*

#### Shorter:

a[**b**] replaced with c(**b**)

*a is known, b is random unknown single word*

It would be great if it takes in mind also white spaces before and after "[" and "]"

Comment: `s/aaaa\[([^\]]*)\]/aaaa(\1)/` Except that this is still not the best because it won't work on e.g. `aaaa[foo[1]]` (because of the nested brackets). It is possible to do better, though, if you need to.

Comment: Yes, but for arrays which accept constans for example it does perfect job, as in my case. Thank you Owen! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just replace `a\[([^\]]*)\]` with `c(\1)`.

For example, you see it working in PHP on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Jm5IS).